# Mac Application :What Cocoa object is this?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface

I am trying to build an App similar to the mail App. In the screenshot below, there is a view that is holding many email services such as google, yahoo and AOL. What is the Cocoa object that is holding all these email services? If you can, check out your mail Application. It doesn't seem to be a custom view, but I can be wrong. The way it drops down from the tool bar looks professional and nice. Perhaps its a combination of a cocoa object and animation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just mean the attached window (as opposed to the controls within it)? That's a [sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowDialogs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH43-SW1). See the [Sheet Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what I am looking for. Thank you.